# How can I see the exit values on NASA CEA run?

Tags: rocket

I'm trying to use the NASA CEA run program to look at what the nozzle design would look like, for just nitrogen gas in a cold gas system. I can see the output values however there is only values at the chamber and throat of the nozzle, not the exit.